# Is it possible to get the process metadata from PM2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I was wondering if it was possible to get process metadata using pm2 inside my node application.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get any information from pm2 inside your app. below will return all running process list. For further details, you can check [pm2-api](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/)

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');
app.use('/all_process_list', function(req,res){

  pm2.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(2);
    }
    pm2.list(function(err, processDescriptionList) {
      console.log(processDescriptionList)
      res.json ({process_list:processDescriptionList})
      pm2.disconnect();   // Disconnects from PM2

    });
  });   
});
```